# Wildcard trigger in Azure Devops not picking up branch changes

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure Devops build pipeline that has multiple branch triggers.  I am using a wildcard to capture changes to branches under refresh/4.*. An example of a branch that I am targeting in this case would be refresh/4.13.0-refresh.  But, the wildcard trigger is not firing when I push new refresh branches.

Here is the trigger definition yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - refs/tags/4.*
      - release/4.x
      - nightly-build
      - refresh/4.*
```

I was expecting this definition to trigger the build action when a new branch such as `refresh/4.9.1-refresh` is pushed to the remote repo. All of the other branch triggers here are succeeding. My hunch is that `-` could be treated as a delimiter. But, I tried updating the trigger to `refresh/4.*-refresh` with no success.

Comment: Will it work when refresh/4.13.0-refresh is specified?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT 
From the Azure Devops Trigger window, I chose to override the YML definition and chose to target the branch specifically.  That worked.

Comment: Since that worked, I tried the wildcard pattern from the post `refresh/4.*` and that actually worked. However, this does not solve my issue. I do not want to move all the trigger definitions from the yml locations that they are currently.

Answer (score 1):

The definition seems correct but is the `- refresh/4.*` line also present in the yml from your *refresh/4.13.0-refresh* branch? If it's a new change to the yml that is only in the main branch for example, then it wouldn't trigger yet.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The tag is present in the refresh branch currently. Also the pipeline is targetting the dev branch for its definition